# SDL Web 8.1.1 Tridion Component Service Crashing

Tags: web8, upgrade

Recently we upgraded Tridion for one of the customer from Tridion 2011 SP1 to SDL Web 8.1.1.

After we upgrade when you say upgrade we installed CMS on the new server

We noticed that the Tridion Content Manager under Component Services  identity is configured to Domain MTS User for some reason even if we don't restart the tridion services  the Tridion Content Manager under Component Services stopped and we get the following error.

Error

> unable to get object: LicenseInfo Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {F470B218-7754-4943-92A5-D264627DD361} failed due to the following error: 8000401a The server process could not be started because the configured identity is incorrect. Check the username and password. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000401A).

To fix we go the component services -> Tridion Component Services -> Properties -> Identity -> re-enter the password and save . Start the Tridion  Component  Services it works.

let us know what could be the reason.

Comment: You say it works after re-entering the password. Does it stop working afterwards and you have to repeat this step?

Comment: when we stop and start the Tridion Content Manager service host  and Tridion Content Manager COM service does not get started , when we edit and change the password of MTSuser on COM+ it works.

Comment: I am facing the same problem in our newly setup server both on DEV and QA environment , the COM service stops quite frequently some sometime twice or thrice in single day. The current work around is to reset the password again. I have raised SDL support ticket for this but still no positive response yet. If someone can find out the actual cause of this issue that will be great.

Comment: i never had this issue, i have done few upgrades before. I will update if I find solution.

Comment: I am still investigating the issue. please let me know is there any options that I can explore.

Comment: On my development I noticed that the component services was not running and it did not have any process id associated. When I accessed the development CMS I noticed the COM+ started and contains process id,there could be some issue with the Domain MTSUser we created on production.

Comment: we executed this command C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis -pa "TridionRsaKeyContainer" DOMAIN\MTSUser . but still the MTS User identity issues occurred please let me know if anybody faced simialr issue or let us know if we can explore any other option to fix this issue. Let us know if we can create a local MTS USer and change  it on COM+ service will that help.

Comment: Component: Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService Errorcode: 3 User: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE StackTrace Information Details: at Tridion.Licensing.LicenseInfo..ctor(String productName, LicenseLockType lockType, String licenseFileName) at Tridion.Licensing.LicenseManager.GetLicenseInfo(String productName, LicenseLockType lockType) at Tridion.Licensing.LicenseManager.GetLicenseInfo(String productName, LicenseLockType lockType) at at Tridion.ContentManager.LicenseHelper.StartupLicenseCheck(Session session) at Tridion.ContentManager.Session..ctor(AccessTokenData accessTokenData, String impersonati

Answer (score 3):

I found and fixed the problem. In short, the domain policy setting was overwriting the Local Security Policy -> "Log on as a batch job"

In the Eventviewer I see the following message, with the same message that is send by the browser.

*"Unable to get object: LicenseInfo
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {F470B218-7754-4943-92A5-D264627DD361} failed due to the following error: 8000401a The server process could not be started because the configured identity is incorrect. Check the username and password. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000401A).*

Component: Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService
Errorcode: 3
User: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE

StackTrace Information Details:
   at Tridion.Licensing.LicenseInfo..ctor(String productName, LicenseLockType lockType, String licenseFileName)
   at Tridion.Licensing.LicenseManager.GetLicenseInfo(String productName, LicenseLockType lockType)
   at Tridion.Licensing.LicenseManager.GetLicenseInfo(String productName, LicenseLockType lockType)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.LicenseHelper.StartupLicenseCheck(Session session)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Session..ctor(String userName, String impersonationUserName)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.CoreServiceBase.Impersonate(String userName)
   at SyncInvokeImpersonate(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.CoreServiceInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)"

Now since this issue is coming up regularly, but not at a exact time, I figured there has to some kind of external process that was messing the server configuration up. Then I read something that the message "Check the username and password" also occurs, when the service can not 'log on as a batch job'.

Right now, when I configure the correct password, I am able to spawn the process, shutdown, spawn again, repeat. As soon as the password is configured, the process is granted "log on as a batch job" rights automatically on the server. You can check this with secpol.msc (rsop.msc doens't work I found).

As soon as the group policy is been updated, these values get overwritten and the service can't start anymore, causing the 'password incorrect' error. You can forcibly test this by running "gpupdate /force". And there it goes: it doesn't work anymore!

I have now added a domain policy, adding the domain MTSUser to "log on as a batch job". This fixes the problem permanently.

Comment: Domain policies can be the server admin's nightmare - I've had a few of my own, including IIS servers not being able to execute .asp pages (old days). Glad you found it!

Comment: Yes, I did the same included the domain MTSUser account in the local policy "Log on as a batch job" and observed for one day now I am not seeing the issue any more.